# `SELECT field AS` to use UNION between 2 tables causes error#1064

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT x.* FROM
(
    (
        SELECT (id,
            insertuserid AS transaction_user_id,
            (user_price * (-1)) AS amount,
            "INVOICE" AS transaction_type,
            insertdatetime
            )
        FROM invoice
        WHERE transaction_user_id = 4
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT (id,
            user_id AS transaction_user_id,
            amount,
            "PAYMENT" AS transaction_type,
            insertdatetime)
        FROM payment
        WHERE user_id = 4
    )
)
AS x
ORDER BY x.insertdatetime
```

The query errors on the first `AS` it sees.

Even when I change `insertuserid AS transaction_user_id` to `insertuserid` in the first `SELECT` of Union, it errors on the second `AS` that is at the next line: `(user_price * (-1)) AS amount`!!!

Error message:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'AS transaction_user_id, (user_price * (-1)) AS amount, "' at line 5


SELECT x.* FROM ( ( SELECT (id, insertuserid AS transaction_user_id,
(user_price * (-1)) AS amount, "INVOICE" AS transaction_type, insertdatetime )
FROM invoice WHERE transaction_user_id = 4 ) UNION
( SELECT (id, user_id AS transaction_user_id, amount,
"PAYMENT" AS transaction_type, insertdatetime) FROM payment
WHERE user_id = 4 ) ) AS x
ORDER BY x.insertdatetime
```

Thank you

Comment: can you post the whole error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just remove the parenthesis on the `SELECT` clause,

```
SELECT  x.* 
FROM
    (
        SELECT  id,
                insertuserid AS transaction_user_id,
                user_price * (-1) AS amount,
                'INVOICE' AS transaction_type,
                insertdatetime
        FROM    invoice
        WHERE   transaction_user_id = 4
        UNION
        SELECT  id,
                user_id AS transaction_user_id,
                amount,
                'PAYMENT' AS transaction_type,
                insertdatetime
        FROM    payment
        WHERE   user_id = 4
    ) AS x
ORDER BY x.insertdatetime
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. More more clearer way of typing. and the error moved a bit further! :D

Comment: Now should I change the first problem and edit it and write the new error or what?! The error is `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INVOICE" AS transaction_type, insertdatetime FROM in' at line 7`

Comment: sorry for the typo on extra `)`, it should be `user_price * (-1) AS amount,` see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you very much. You used less braces and more clearly in writing the code!